# автоматическая генерация полей

Tags: modx

Можно ли в  migx генерировать одно поле на основе другого ? Как это сделано когда сохраняешь заголовок и на основе заголовка автоматически генерируется  псевдоним(alias)

```
$eventName = $modx->event->name;
switch($eventName) {
    case 'OnDocFormSave':
        //если у ресурса шаблон=5
        if ($resource->get('template') == 32) {
            // после сохранения значение ТВ price=128
            if(!$resource->setTVValue('seotitle', 'title')) {
                $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Возникли проблемы при установке значения ТВ.');
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

пытаюсь так

Comment: Не очень понимаю зачем это нужно, если у вас одно поле полностью вычисляется на основе другого (других) полей, зачем вам его хранить в отдельном поле? делайте генерацию при выводе. Но если нужно, Вы можете сделать плагин OnTVFormSave - (вызывается после записи tv поля), там вы получите необходимые поля вычислите новое и запишите его

Comment: у меня просто ссылки берутся на основе заголовка который в статьях, и что бы человек каждый раз не делал лишние действия, нужно что бы при сохранение это поле обновлялось на основе заголовка который он ввёл вначале

Comment: тогда через плагин можно сделать

Comment: поправил ответ, взгляните пожалуйста

Comment: не сработало почему-то

Comment: Сейчас проверил ваш вариант, у меня все сохраняется

Comment: может я не правильно его вызываю, событие не срабатывает при сохранении

Comment: Вы в закладке "Системные события" на этом плагине отметили `OnDocFormSave`?